# Execute $http requests in a particular order

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have about 5 requests that are made when my view loads.  This is for an edit form:

```
var reqA = function() {...};
var reqB = function() {...};
var reqC = function() {...};
var reqD = function() {...};
var reqE = function() {...};
```

Now I want `reqA()` and `reqB()` to load asynchronously and if possible return a single promise.

`reqC()` and `reqD()` should only load **after** `reqA()` and `reqB()` have finished and executed their promise.

`reqE()` should only load **after** `reqC()` and `reqD()`.

This is what I want to do, however I have no idea how to go about it. I can load them all asynchronously or one after another by chaining promises but not in the way I want.

Comment: check out the `$q` module

Comment: You can use `$q.all()` to create a promise that resolves after an array of promises resolve. e.g. `$q.all([reqA(), reqB()]).then(() => reqC())`

Comment: @rob tried your code and it seems off, my IDE underlines it.  COuld you please explain more.

Comment: Please try and update your title so that it is about your actual question, not just a couple of keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your functions all use the `$http` provider, it is easy to accomplish. You will want to modify your functions to return the result of the `$http` call like this

```
function reqA() {
  return $http.get(...);
}
```

Now that they are returning promises, you can easily use the $q provider to orchestrate your requests:

```
$q.all([reqA(), reqB()])
.then( () => 
  $q.all([reqC(), reqD()])
  .then(() => reqE()) 
 );
```

For regular JS (non ES6):

```
$q.all([reqA(), reqB()])
.then(function() {
  $q.all([reqC, reqD()])
  .then(function() {
    reqE();
  });
});
```

If you don't want to return the result of `$http` in your functions, you will need to set them up to return a promise in one way or the other:

```
function reqA() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  ... your request code ...
  // call this if everything is ok
  deferred.resolve();
  // call this if there was an error
  deferred.reject();
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer helped me a lot, I will read more about this "$q" thingy for a better understanding. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](https://jsbin.com/fahoqawaba/1/edit?js,console) that you can take a look at that might make it clearer.  It makes use of [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which is globally available in almost all javascript environments (excluding IE and older node versions).

```
   angular
  .module('example', [])
  .run(function($q) {
    function requestOne() {
      return $q.when("one")
    }

    function requestTwo() {
      return $q.when("two")
    }

    function requestThree() {
      return $q.when("three")
    }

    function requestFour() {
      return $q.when("four")
    }

    function requestFive() {
      return $q.when("five")
    }

    $q
      .all([requestOne(), requestTwo()])
      .then(function(responses){
        console.log(responses[0] === "one");
        console.log(responses[1] === "two");

        return $q.all([requestThree(), requestFour()]);
      })
      .then(function(nextResponses){
        console.log(nextResponses[0] === "three");
        console.log(nextResponses[1] === "four")

        return requestFive();
      })
      .then(function(lastResponse){
        console.log(lastResponse === "five")
      })
});

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, [ 'example' ]);
});
```

I assume that you are using angular 1, if you aren't there [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is available in the global scope in almost all environments.